# Package Load Failure in Visual Studio 2008 after Windows Updates Installed

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I just shut down my computer last night, which forced Windows to install new updates; something like "Windows is installing updates. Do not turn off your computer. Installing x of 80 updates." Then I started up my computer.

Now I can't open any project in Visual Studio 2008. I get popup dialog with message "Package Load Failure. Package 'Windows Forms Designer Hosting Package' has failed to load properly", and similar popup dialogs for other packages like Jetbrains and ANTS Profiler.

Here's what I tried:

- using command prompt to run "devenv /resetskippkgs"
- doing an install repair of Visual Studio 2008
- uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2008
- uninstalling and reinstalling other versions of Visual Studio on my computer
- installing VS 2008 SP1 (this installation actually fails, because of some "An unhandled exception (System.IO.FileLoadException) occurred in AddInUtil.exe.")

Nothing seems to work. Is there anything else I can try? I'm blocked from being able to complete any of my tasks right now.

Comment: Maybe a repair of .NET also? .NET 2 or other versions installed on your machine. Also, check what's been installed in the upgrades, there may be something that will ring a bell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had problems with visual studio, when upgrading to `visual studio professional 2012` - which I may add I got free, as a programming student through `Microsoft Dreamspark`.

Firstly, checking fundamentals ( although I doubt this is your problem).

1. Are you using the computer as a user with **Administrative rights**?
   I suspect you are, but if not, you need to have administrative rights.
2. Have you checked if any **files are being blocked by your firewall**?
   When I switched to the full version of Avast I find I have to disable the **File System Shield** It loves to remove my executable files when I try to run my visual studio projects.

What I did, was I ended up uninstalling EVERYTHING that was associated with both Visual Studio downloads. If you are able to remove and save your project files elsewhere and then bring them back. Go through all your program files to see if there is anything hidden in the wrong folder and check your C drive.

*TIP* **For EVERY project I write I copy and paste into a text file (in notepad plus) and then email it to myself - the formdesigner, form and any modules, classes etc. I do this for ALL my programs in ALL languages. That way if there is a problem with the software or my pc I can recreate the projects without too much ado.**

Which meant downloading and reinstalling (fresh):

1. Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29
2. `.Net Framework` (you would need 3.5 plus a service pack)
   The following link provides links for the framework and service pack.
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22
3. The `Visual Studio 2008` SP1 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10986
4. And the `SDK`.
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=508

This is a link from the MSDN about installing Visual Studio 2008
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175908(v=vs.90).aspx

This is a link from Aaron Sterbner's web blog:
It is trouble shooting `VS 2005`, but he discusses in detail how to clean out your files.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/11/09/491118.aspx

If this doesn't work, then we'll have to check for programs that may be interfering with `VS`. However, as other programs have been affected Jetbrains and ANTS Profiler

I think if you clean out your program files, it should be ok. I wouldn't recommend going into your `register` unless you are very sure of what you are doing. **IF** you have already made changes to the register then we'll have a look at that and other options (if this doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, uninstalling all redistributable packs, service packs and eventually entire visual studio and then reinstalling everything back worked. Not the greatest solution but it is good to have my environment back to sane form.

Comment: Same here, nothing else I tried fixed this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I just had that same problem, what I did to solve it was running AVG tuneup utilities, which cleans up the unnecessary files from the registry and defragmensts it, removes broken shortcuts, and so on.

It worked for me, maybe will work for you as well